# Check whether EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE exist in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am new to Azure SQL Database. I have a `EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` as listed in following link.

[CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=dedicated)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [My_data_src] WITH (TYPE = RDBMS, LOCATION = N'myserver', CREDENTIAL = [my_cred], DATABASE_NAME = N'MyDB')
```

GO

Before creating a new EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE, I need to find out whether this already exists. is there any query or dmv existing to find this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following command give you list of all existing External Data Source in database

```sql
select  *  from sys.external_data_sources;
```

To check particular External Data Source, exist or not use following command:

```sql
IF  EXISTS (
SELECT  name
FROM sys.external_data_sources
WHERE [name] =  'Name of Datasource'
)
BEGIN
PRINT  'Yes'
END
```

**It will print Yes if Data Source Exist.**

Refer - [sys.external_data_sources (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-external-data-sources-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)